Proving that a pair of "snow angels" cannot tile the plane
I hope to better understand how to show that a tile cannot successfully tile the plane. Consider a "snow angel" and its mirror image of the form below:

I believe that I cannot tile the plane using this pair of tiles.
I think this because I keep running into issues (which I mark with red dots below) when trying to patch these together to cover large disks in the plane.
For example, the face marked with a red dot cannot be filled:

With a different fitting together of the tiles, there are a pair of faces that now can no longer be simultaneously filled:


How can I prove that this pair of snow angels cannot tile the plane?

Note that in the green tile, all triangles at its edge are pointing up. Similarly, for the blue tile they are pointing down. It follows that neither tile on its own can tile the plane. So a tiling must include a green tile.
Consider the gap at its bottom right, marked with a red dot in your first image. This must be filled by a triangle pointing down, hence by a blue tile. Moreover, both its top edge and left edge must be at the edge of the blue tile, leaving precisely two ways in which the gap can be filled.
One of these two ways is shown in your second picture. The gap marked by the leftmost dot must be filled by a triangle pointing down, hence by a blue tile, and with its left edge exposed. There is only one way to do so. But now the gap marked by the other dot is not tiled, but surrounded by three blue triangles. So this option does not lead to a tiling of the plane.
The other option is entirely analogous, again not leading to a tiling of the plane. This shows that these two tiles do not tile the plane.

Thank you for the thorough answer! I hadn't appreciated how close I was. I needed to be more systematic, however.
